# how to select an option by index in capabara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I want to select second option using index in following tree.

```
<select id="buy_buy_options" name="buy[buy_options]" required="required">
<option value="" selected="selected">one</option>
<option value="16190937"> one</option>
<option value="16190939">Two</option>
</select>
```

I don't want to use value or text just by index. How I can do it ?
I am using Capybara with cucumber

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS selector:

```
find('#buy_buy_options > option:nth-child(2)').click
```

or XPath:

```
find(:xpath, "//select[@id='buy_buy_options']/option[2]").click
```